# How to find the sum of every 4 elements of a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Like here is a list:

```
[2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
```

Here is the output I want:

output:

```
[8,12,16]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
In [1]: l = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]

In [2]: [sum(l[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(l), 4)]
Out[2]: [8, 12, 16]
```

Comment: This is fine as long as the list is a multiple of four; you can do `[i:min(i + 4, len(l) - 1)]` instead to make it more robust.

Comment: @asthasr The list won't give an error if the slicing value is greater than the length of the list.

Comment: @asthasr no, it will work either way. Using `min` doesn't make it any more robust

Comment: Ah, fair. I forget that behavior of Python :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
from math import ceil
result = []
for i in range(ceil(len(L)/4)):
    result += [sum(L[i*4:i*4+4])]
```

If you want to avoid importing ceil, here's another way:

```
result = []
for i in range((len(L)+3)//4):
    result += [sum(L[i*4:i*4+4])]
```

These solutions work even when the list length is not a multiple of 4, in which case the remaining elements are summed together. So the output for a list like

```
L = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,3]
```

Would be:

```
[8, 12, 16, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option by grouping your list to a list of lists with each 4 values using the [grouper](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) function and then sum the values in each list like this:

```
from more_itertools import grouper
your_list = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
your_lists = list(grouper(4, your_list))
list(map(sum, your_lists))
```

Output:

```
[8, 12, 16]
```